# Navigation drawer and floating button not working simultaneously

Tags: android

Firstly, I have implemented navigation drawer and it was working fine and then I implemented floating action button on the same screen. Floating button is also working fine but when I am opening my navigation drawer, then menu items of navigation drawer are not working. So, when integrating navigation drawer with floating action button then menu items of navigation drawer are not working.

My Java code:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

//widgets
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
public ViewPager mViewPager;

//vars
public SectionsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

//navigation drawer
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

//user info
TextView uname,uemail;
String pemail,pname;
ImageView pimage;

FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    pimage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.pimage);
    uname = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.uname);
    uemail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.emailo);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SearchActivity.this);
    pemail = sharedPref.getString("email", "Not Available");
    pname = sharedPref.getString("username", "Not Available");

    uname.setText(pname);
    uemail.setText(pemail);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,Post.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    setupFirebaseListener();
    verifyPermissions();

}

private void setupFirebaseListener() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseListener: setting up the auth state listener.");
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_in: " + user.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_out");
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupViewPager(){
    mPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment());
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(new WatchListFragment());
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PostFragment());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_search));
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_watch_list));
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_post));
}

private void verifyPermissions(){
    Log.d(TAG, "verifyPermissions: asking user for permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            permissions[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        setupViewPager();
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchActivity.this,
                permissions,
                REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    verifyPermissions();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.profile){

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,test.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if(id == R.id.aboutus){

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,Aboutus.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(this,"About Us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if(id == R.id.mypost){

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,MyPosts.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(this,"My Post",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if(id == R.id.filters){

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FiltersActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Filter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if(id == R.id.logout){

        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to sign out the user.");
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

    }

    if(id == R.id.logout){

        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to sign out the user.");
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

    }
    return false;}
```

and my xml file is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                >

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_container"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/postads"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            fab:layout_editor_absoluteX="342dp"
            fab:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp" ></com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should have only one main content `View` inside the `DrawerLayout`. That is, put the `<AppBarLayout>`, the `<ViewPager>`, and the `<FloatingActionButton>` all inside the `<CoordinatorLayout>`, and then move that to before the `<NavigationView>`.

Comment: thanks a lot...it worked!!!